# Problemas con Arreglos en Javascript

Tags: javascript, arraylist, objeto, async-await, push

Tengo un problema al querer llenar este arreglo ya que quiero usar el foreach para recorrer lo que contiene pero al momento de verlo y llamar el lenght me muestra que este es de 0

[image: Salida de consola al momento de llamar el arreglo]

En la salida se puede observar que tengo un arreglo de prueba con tres objetos, y este muestra que tiene un largo de 3 y muestra la salida de los objetos, caso contrario al arreglo siguiente que tiene 6 objetos y no muestra ni su largo o su contenido..!

```
const Template = async () => {
     let pokeTemplateList = []
     let pokeCard;
     randomIds().forEach(id => {
         fetchData(id)
         .then(value => {
             let poke = {};
             poke['id'] = value.id; 
             poke['name'] = value.name; 
             poke['sprite'] = value.sprite;
             pokeTemplateList.push(poke)
         })
     })
     console.log(pokeTemplateList)
     console.log(pokeTemplateList.length)
     return pokeTemplateList
 }
```

Cabe resaltar que lo que estoy intentando realizar es una petición a la POKEAPI en donde genero un random de números y llamo realizo un fetch pasando cada ID, esta función fetchData la importo de otro documento siendo una función asíncrona

```
const fetchData = async (id) => {
    const apiUrl = `${BASEURL}pokemon/${id}`
    try {
         const res = await fetch(apiUrl)
         const response = await res.json()

         var poke = {
             "id":response.id,
             "name": response.name,
             "sprite":response.sprites.front_default,
             "types": [],
         } 
         return poke

     } catch (error) {
         console.log(error)
     };
 };
```

soy nuevo en promesas y leyendo encontré que para obtener el valor de cada una tengo que llamar a la función then(), la cual tiene un callback y en esta paso nuevamente la respuesta a una variable y posteriormente le hago un push() para mi nuevo arreglo el cual es el del problema.

Me gustaría tener una explicación de si estoy haciendo algo mal o en si cual es el problema de porque son distintos estos arreglos..!

Comment: Tu app funciona correctamente? o simplemente tienes la duda de por que en la consola muestra que el array no tiene contenido pero al expanderlo si contiene algo? Se muestra vacio porque al momento que se imprime el arreglo este no contiene nada porque es asincrono, pero cuando se expande este ya tiene el contenido. De alguna manera console guarda una referencia a este arreglo/objeto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que estas realizando una llama asincronica dentro del `forEach` y no estas esperando a que se resuelva para imprimir el resultado.

Una solución simple es reemplazar el `forEach` con un `for` y usar `await` para esperar el resultado del `fetchData`.

#### Ejemplo:

```
const Template = async () => {
     let pokeTemplateList = []
     let pokeCard;
     let ids = randomIds();

     for(let i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
         let value = await fetchData(id);
         let poke = {};
         poke['id'] = value.id; 
         poke['name'] = value.name; 
         poke['sprite'] = value.sprite;
         pokeTemplateList.push(poke)
     }
     console.log(pokeTemplateList)
     console.log(pokeTemplateList.length)
     return pokeTemplateList
 }
```

Comment: Gracias hermano créeme que me cuesta entender un poco el concepto de lo que es sin crono y asíncrono, me ha costado un poco ya que soy primerizo, vengo un poco mas de la lógica del backend y estoy queriendo aprender frontend así como a consumir API'S pero enserió gracias me funciono tu explicación.